# Set up triple integral's boundary for $x^{2} + (y-a)^{2} + z^{2}=a^{2}$ in spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I have trouble with setting up triple integral's boundary for $\rho$.
Solid object's equation is $x^{2} + (y-a)^{2} + z^{2}=a^{2}$,which is a sphere centered at (0,a,0), in spherical coordinates.
Note: a is just a constant.

Comment: Switch to the variables $x'=x, y'=y-a, z'=z$. Now your sphere is centered at the origin.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro it's a good idea , but if we want to strict  to directly setting up, how can we do ?

Comment: Besides , purpose of the question is understand how can we set up to the $\rho$ in this situation not to find volume of the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to translate the sphere so that its center lies in the origin, you will have to plug the spherical coordinate change in the inequality 
$$\tag{*}
x^2+(y-a)^2+z^2 \le a^2.$$
Namely, using the following convention: 
$$
\begin{cases}
 x=r\sin \theta \cos \phi \\
 y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi \\ 
 z=r\cos \theta
\end{cases}, \qquad r\in [0, \infty),\ \theta\in [0, \pi],\ \phi\in [0, 2\pi),
$$
one has 
$$
\tag{*}
r^2 -2ar\sin\theta\sin\phi \le 0.$$
Note that this inequality has no solutions for $\phi\notin[0, \pi]$. (This is easy to visualize geometrically as well).

This means that the solid ball can be rewritten in spherical coordinates as follows: 
$$
\left\{ 
 (r, \theta, \phi)\ :\ r\le 2a\sin\theta\sin\phi, \phi\in[0, \pi],\ \theta\in[0, \pi] \right\}. $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.