# Rewriting triple integrals rectangular, cylindrical, and spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Write three integrals, one in Cartesian/rectangular, one in cylindrical, and one in spherical coordinates, that calculate the average of the function $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2$ on the region $E$ in the first octant inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 9$, and above the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

The volume of $E$ is provided, $E = \frac{9\pi}{4}(2-\sqrt{2})$. Only the setup is needed, the integrals do not need to be evaluated.

I have the spherical and cylindrical integrals but I'm not quite sure of my bounds:

$\frac{1}{Vol(E)}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{3}\rho^4 \sin^3(\phi) d\rho d\phi d\theta$

$\frac{1}{Vol(E)}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}}\int_{r}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}}r^3dz dr d\theta$

Comment: Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836487/how-do-i-set-up-the-triple-integral-in-cylindrical-coordinates?noredirect=1. Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396108/on-triple-integration-using-spherical-coordinates?noredirect=1. Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291054/triple-integral-in-different-coordinate-systems. You may only need the last link.Another:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606630/set-up-triple-integrals-boundary-for-x2-y-a2-z2-a2-in-spher?noredirect=1,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870008/triple-integration-in-vector-calc

Comment: _How exactly do you go about writing these integrals?_ you need to study about it somewhere, practice simple questions and build on it. One place to get started - https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/tripleintegrals.aspx

Comment: @MathLover Apologies, I needed to elaborate a little further. I wasn't sure if I started it off right but this is my progress so far.

Comment: @Ajay Thanks again Ajay, the links helped! :)

Comment: Yes your edit helps and in fact it is correct, except that you need to consider only first octant so the upper bound of $\theta$ should be $\pi/2$. Before your edit, the way your question read seemed like you were asking guidance on where to start with such integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your work is correct except the bounds of $\theta$. Please note that the region is in the first octant so $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

In cartesian coordinates, note that at the intersection of the sphere and the cone,

$x^2 + y^2 = 9 - z^2 = 9 - x^2 - y^2 \implies x^2 + y^2 = 9/2$

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{3/\sqrt2} \int_0^{\sqrt{9/2-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}} (x^2 + y^2) ~ dz ~ dy ~ dx$

Comment: I see. So the original $\theta$ bound would’ve accounted for the entire graph, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It would have accounted for the entire volume bound above the cone and inside the sphere.

Comment: Got it, thank you.